# pdflib certain unicode characters not rendering

Tags: php, unicode, truetype, pdflib

I need to compose a pdf using [pdflib version 8](http://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/manuals/PDFlib-8.0.2-API-reference-Windows.pdf),
In which I need to print certain unicode characters

But they are not getting rendered ,Instead below characters are displaying

[€](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20aC/index.htm)

What could be the reason & How can I render the characters?

**Below is the code**

```
$p = PDF_new();

/*  open new PDF file; insert a file name to create the PDF on disk */
if (PDF_begin_document($p, "", "") == 0) {
    die("Error: " . PDF_get_errmsg($p));
}
PDF_set_info($p, "Creator", "Abc");
PDF_set_info($p, "Author", "Abc");
PDF_set_info($p, "Title", "Test");
pdf_set_option($p, "textformat=utf8");

PDF_begin_page_ext($p, 595, 842, "");
$fontdir = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu';
pdf_set_parameter($p, "FontOutline", "Dejavu=$fontdir/DejaVuSans.ttf");
$font = pdf_load_font($p, "Dejavu", "unicode","");

PDF_setfont($p, $font, 24.0);
PDF_set_text_pos($p, 50, 700);
pdf_show_xy($p,"dejb €",100,490);
pdf_show_xy($p,"dejb  ",200,490);
PDF_end_page_ext($p, "");

PDF_end_document($p, "");

$buf = PDF_get_buffer($p);
$len = strlen($buf);

header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Length: $len");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=hello.pdf");
print $buf;

PDF_delete($p);
```

**Output**

[image]

**Edit:**

Tried using freesans font instead of dejavu, but no change in the output.

```
$fontdir = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont';
pdf_set_parameter($p, "FontOutline", "FreeSans=$fontdir/FreeSans.ttf");
$font = pdf_load_font($p, "FreeSans", "unicode","")
```

Comment: try to use freesans instead of dejavusans

Comment: @donald123 no it dint work. no change in the output. check the updated question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve your problem by using a font that contains the required glyphs. When you check the page of your linked page "MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL A" you can see a link to the "[Fonts that support U+1D44E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d44e/fontsupport.htm)":

As you can see, just a few fonts support this glyph, for example "**DejaVu Serif Italic**". When I use DejaVu Serif Italic  (DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf) from the DejaVu package I get the expected output:

[image]

Of course also other fonts might support this glyphs and you are not limited to DejaVuSans Serif.

Just one note to your code: The line:

```
pdf_set_option($p, "textformat=utf8");
```

requires PDFlib 9. Please use

```
PDF_set_parameter($p, "textformat", "utf8");
```

instead.

Comment: Using the supported help does fix the problem. However my content in dynamic and requires me to change between `DevajuSerif-Italic` and  `DejaVuSerif` every few characters. One way to solve this is to split the string and keep changing the fonts between sub strings. Is there an elegant solution?

Comment: you might use the `fallbackfonts `option. (see starter_fallback.php sample in the package or http://www.pdflib.com/en/pdflib-cookbook/fonts/starter-fallback/) In this case you can specify a font, where missing glyphs should be searched too.